# Material Ledger consistency check function module

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi

Is there a function module or BAPI or method that nicely performs a material/material ledger consistency check for a given material?

I am aware of report `SAPRCKMU` which would be very hard to use inside my own program.

I am also aware of and using function module `CKML_F_CKML1_PRICES_GET` which performs a consistency check.

When this function module finds an inconsistency, it calls `MESSAGE E`... which means I lose control in my program. This is the core problem that I have.

So I am searching a way to check consistency before I call `CKML_F_CKML1_PRICES_GET` in a way that gives me a return parameter with the error message without calling `MESSAGE E`....

Comment: Can't you handle this `E` messages by using `EXCEPTIONS OTHERS = 99.`?

Comment: @Jagger  I think this lead me in the right direction. Note to self: try `EXCEPTIONS error_message = 99`

Comment: I'm wondering why you need a own consistency check at all?!? There are already a variety of reports available in the material ledger help desk (Tx CKMHELP), for checking consistency of materials, valuation areas and customizing in this area.

Comment: I wanted to check because `call CKML_F_CKML1_PRICES_GET` did not return nicely because there is a statement `MESSAGE E...` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works very well:

add the line `error_message = 99` to the function module call:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CKML_F_CKML1_PRICES_GET'
   ....
EXCEPTIONS 
   ...
   error_message = 99
   others = 98.
```

Now the program doesn't interrupt the control flow when the function module itself uses `MESSAGE E...` instead of `RAISE ...`.

Whenever `MESSAGE E...` is called inside, it is converted into `SY-SUBRC = 99` and the error-fields in `SY-...` are also set.